# Which is bigger, a 32 bit address space or a 16KB address space?

Tags: memory, virtual-memory

[A recent sentence I read](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/vm-smalltables.pdf) stated "Most of the page table is unused, full of invalid entries. And this is for a tiny 16KB address space. Imagine the page table of a 32-bit address space and all the potential wasted space in there!"

This suggests a 32-bit address space is larger than a 16KB address space, which is confusing as 32 bits is significantly smaller than 16KB

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it may just be a sloppy use of words.

- "16 KB address space" refers to the actual size of the address space.
- "32 bit address space" refers to the size of the address space *addressable by a 32 bit address*.  This is 4 GB.

A 16 KB address space is addressable by a 14 bit address.

Comment: Reading the source document (I added a link in the question) confirms this. The introduction explains things to some extent...

Comment: Thanks @Kusalananda that clears things up in my head, appreciate it